# Is it possible to modify the existing excel file using maatwebsite?

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am developing a laravel project.

Importing excel files using Maatwebsite was a success.

I want to edit and save the imported excel file.

Is it possible to edit and save some data while maintaining all functions including the formula of excel file?

Please advise.

Answer (score -1):

Yes sir, you can do it. Please try this code :

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

If this code isn't work, visit this laravel-excel documentation for more : [Laravel-excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/)

Good luck sir! there must be a way..